# Exchange Webservice using Oauth throws error when subscribing a resource

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I am using OAuth2.0 to connect to Exchange webservices. Everything else seems to work ok for me . However when i try to subscribe one of the room resource by using grouping info and providing the anchor mailbox as one of the primary mail box it throws an error.

**"Request failed because EWS could not contact the appropriate CAS server for this request."**

So for example i am trying to subscribe nitroom1 and one the primary mailbox associated with the group is nitroom2 which i am using as X-AnchorMailbox then i got the above error.

```
public static ExchangeService GetExchangeService(string exchangeURL, string userName, string password, string resourceEmail, string primaryMailbox, string clientID, string tenantID, string clientSecret, string certName)
    {
        ExchangeService service;
        service = new ExchangeService(setTZtoUTC);
        service.Url = new Uri(exchangeURL);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientID) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantID))
        {
            string oAuthToken = multiExchangeManager.getOAuthTokenFromCache(clientID, tenantID, clientSecret, certName);
            service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(oAuthToken);
        }
        else
        {
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);
        }
        service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, resourceEmail);
        service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", primaryMailbox);
        service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-PreferServerAffinity", "true");
        return service;
    }
```

However if i connect ews using impersonate account then do same thing it works fine.

Also, if i use resourceMailbox same as primary mailbox then it works ok as well.so in my example it will look like this.

```
 service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "nitroom1");
        service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "nitroom1");
```

This is how i am trying to use subscription.

```
exchangeService.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
                new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems },
                EventType.Created, EventType.Deleted, EventType.Modified, EventType.Moved, EventType.Copied);
```

Does anyone have any idea why its happening or what i am doing wrong here?

one more thing to add, i tried EWSEditor tool which provides subscription info and both above mentioned resources sharing same grouping info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a solution for this issue, i just need to set 
X-BackEndOverRideCookie with any service used for subscribing child mailbox.

For more info read this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-maintain-affinity-between-group-of-subscriptions-and-mailbox-server